# Prevent focus to call blur functionality

Tags: javascript, html

I am validating an email address and creating an alert message if the validation fails. When user clicks "Ok" on the alert message, focus should be returned to email address text box.

I am facing a problem with focus functionality which is calling blur and blur functionality in turn again calls focus. It is running in infinite loop. Pls refer example below -

[BlurAndFocusIssue](https://jsfiddle.net/learnRC/ktuzvw02/1/)

```
input.onblur = function() {
  samp.innerHTML="Called blur";
  if (!input.value.includes('@')) { 
    input.classList.add('invalid');
    alert('Please enter a correct email.');
    document.getElementById("input").focus();
  }
};


input.onfocus = function() {
  samp.innerHTML="Called focus";
  if (this.classList.contains('invalid')) {
    this.classList.remove('invalid');
    error.innerHTML = "";
  }
};
```

Once focus is inside email address, i need to allow the user to enter the email address and get it validated on onBlur functionality..

Comment: `input.onblur = function(e) { e.preventDefault() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` to control `Onblur`

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktuzvw02/4/)**

```
input.onblur = function() {
  samp.innerHTML="Called blur";
  var validating = false; //<-- IMPORTANT
  if (!input.value.includes('@')) { 
    input.classList.add('invalid');
     if(validating == false) {
              validating = true
              alert('Please enter a correct email.');
              setTimeout(function(){
              input.focus();
              validating = false;
            }, 1);
     }
  }
};


input.onfocus = function() {
  samp.innerHTML="Called focus";
  if (this.classList.contains('invalid')) {
    this.classList.remove('invalid');
    error.innerHTML = "";
  }
};
```

Comment: I see that this solution is working, however, when i focus to another window and come back to Chrome browser, its going in to infinite loop as focus calls blur and blur as code to focus.